# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: offset (0) + length (8) exceed the capacity of the array: 4

Tags: scala, hbase

Getting this error while running spark job for reading the data from Hbase . Thanks.

Here is the code

```
val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])

    hBaseRDD.count()

    // transform (ImmutableBytesWritable, Result) tuples into an RDD of Result’s
    val resultRDD = hBaseRDD.map(tuple => tuple._2)
    resultRDD.count()
    // transform into an RDD of (RowKey, ColumnValue)s  the RowKey has the time removed
    val keyValueRDD = resultRDD.map(result => (Bytes.toString(result.getRow()).split(" ")(0), Bytes.toDouble(result.value)))
    keyValueRDD.take(3).foreach(kv => println(kv))

    // group by rowkey , get statistics for column value
    val keyStatsRDD = keyValueRDD.groupByKey().mapValues(list => StatCounter(list))
    keyStatsRDD.take(5).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem most time is the type error. Please double check the type of your data.

Answer (score 0):

One option for this error is if you stored an Int (4B) and are trying to read it into a Double or Long (8B).

E.g.

```scala
// Write an Int
table.put(
    new Put(Bytes.toBytes(key))
        .addColumn(
            Bytes.toBytes("family"),
            Bytes.toBytes("qualifier"),
            Bytes.toBytes(1)))) // Write 1 instead of 1.0

// Attempt to read as a Double
val getResult = table.get(new Get(Bytes.toBytes(key)))
for (cell <- cells if (Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneQualifier(cell)) == "qualifier")) {

    val value = Bytes.toDouble(CellUtil.cloneValue(cell))
}
```

If this is the case, possible solutions, that I know of, are:

1. Cast before writing to the correct type
2. On read, check value's Bytes.length before casting to Double/Long, if the result if 4, then cast to Int instead